# Why is block selection characterwise?

Tags: cursor-motions, visual-mode

Looking at the documentation I found this piece:

```
a}                          *v_a}* *a}* *a{*
a{                          *v_aB* *v_a{* *aB*
aB          "a Block", select [count] Blocks, from "[count] [{" to
            the matching '}', including the '{' and '}' (see
            |[{|).
            When used in Visual mode it is made characterwise.
```

The part interesting here is

> When used in Visual mode it is made characterwise.

It's the behavior for all the `i`/`a` text objects (except for `p`)

Do you know why is the visual selection changed ?

Why can't you select a block linewise? (e.g. `Va{` will jump back to characterwise).

Comment: `Why can't you select a block linewise?` Not an answer to 'why' but you can easily select a block in linewise mode: `viB` to select the block and then `V` will switch from characterwise to linewise.

Comment: @statox But that's just it, using `VaB` still doesn't use linewise. It switches it back to characterwise.

Comment: @Tumbler41 yeah `V` has to be pressed after `vaB` to switch to lineswise, but that's not a perfect solution clearly

Comment: @statox Ah, I didn't know you could do that. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

From my observation: Because there isn't a linewise version of `di{`.  In the same vein, there isn't a characterwise version of `dip`.  Not to mention that `Viw` would seemingly do nothing if `iw` didn't cause it to become characterwise.

As far as I can tell, text objects are basically macros for selecting text.  When you use an operator command, the text is "selected" before being operated on.  In visual mode, the text objects simply become visible.

It seems reasonable that using text objects in visual mode would replace the selection since they can't be used to extend the selection.  That is, if you selected a few characters then press `i{`, the initial selection is lost since it would otherwise *not* be "text that's between two curly braces".

For example:

```
if (1) {
   // <- start selection in here
}

// <- end the selection here and press `i{`
```